# Authenticate between microservices in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have to implement authentication between few microservies in Java 8, Spring (Boot, Security) and actually I'm looking for good solution. Could you give me some tips what technologies should I recognise? At this moment I have been reading about Spring OAuth, but maybe you know some better solutions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I searh the same thing with you, and actually i start to learn about OpenAM, or OpenSSO, so i find it a good solution specially if your system is big and you have multiple applications like microservices.

Comment: Use Spring OAuth with JWT / OpenConnect ID. Or use external authentication with Keycloak: http://keycloak.jboss.org/ (provides Spring Security module)